# Flutter version solving failed firebase_auth ^1.4.1 and http ^0.12.2

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm new in flutter.
I was trying to add `http: ^0.12.2` package in my flutter project, the existing `firebase` packages are clashing and I'm not able to add the http package.

I tried changing the channel to dev.
Also tried adding the old package of `http ^0.10.0` still the problem persists.
This is the error that I'm getting

```
Running "flutter pub get" in fsp...                             
Because firebase_auth_web 1.3.1 depends on http_parser ^4.0.0 and no versions of firebase_auth_web match >1.3.1 <2.0.0, firebase_auth_web ^1.3.1 requires http_parser ^4.0.0.
And because http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0, http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 is incompatible with firebase_auth_web ^1.3.1.
And because firebase_auth 1.4.1 depends on firebase_auth_web ^1.3.1 and no versions of firebase_auth match >1.4.1 <2.0.0, http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 is incompatible with firebase_auth ^1.4.1.
So, because match11 depends on both firebase_auth ^1.4.1 and http ^0.12.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because match11 depends on both firebase_auth ^1.4.1 and http ^0.12.2, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Following is my `pubspec.yaml` file

```
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.4
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
  firebase_database: ^7.1.1
  provider: ^5.0.0
  path: ^1.7.0
  http: ^0.12.2
loading_animations: "^2.1.0"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.0
flutter_native_splash: 
  color: "#2d63d6"
  image: assets/splash.jpg
  android: true
  ios: true
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:

    - assets/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because, as the message say, `firebase_auth` needs `http_parser` to be exactly ^4.0.0, but at the same time, `http` requires `http_parser` to be less than ^4.0.0.

you have two options, either you downgrade `firebase_auth` or you upgrade `http`. the thing is, you cannot know which versions will actually work with each other.

you can run this command to understand more

```
dart pub outdated
```

this will give you an output like [this](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-outdated#example).

in the upgradable column, it tells you what packages have an update.

in the resolvable column, it tills you what packages you are able to update(if there is any), because sometimes there is resolving issues, that's what's happening with you.

so downgrading `firebase_auth` might work, if it did, and you want the latest version of it, run this command to see what's resolvable, for both `firebase_auth` and `http`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to resolve it using ```flutter pub outdated``` command. First I upated `firebase_auth` & `firebase_core` seperately then I ran `flutter pub upgrade` and upgraded rest of the packages, after that I was able to install the `http` package.