# Flutter: Error with existing http dependency

Tags: flutter

First post so forgive me if I don't make any sense! I'm attempting to connect firebase to my app. It currently says that there is an http dependency that is preventing me from adding the http_parser dependency needed. If I try to delete either dependency then I receive several errors. Any help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlVg2.png)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012874/flutter-version-solving-failed-firebase-auth-1-4-1-and-http-0-12-2/69014371#69014371

Answer (score 0):

if your project migrated to `null safety` then simply use the `newest version` of each `dependency` you have especially those who depend on each other, since `http_parser` also uses a `http`, or else match the version for each other.

Comment: That makes sense however both dependencies are up to date. Its saying that it requires http_parser to be <4.0.0 but it is currently ^4.0.0. Downgrading to an older version also didnt work for me. Is there anything else that could potentially solve this issue ?

Comment: well i suggest you to try older version of each until you find the perfect match, i been using flutter for two years now and yet couldn't figure out the error, if just in case you project is migrated to `null safety` then use older `null safety` versions or just try them all till you find the match, or once you import new packages try `flutter pub get` and restart the `IDE` or the `Editor` that must help in case.